# Create a spreadsheet-like form with Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I've been learning Rails for about two months now. I'm creating an application for teachers to track the progress of their students. I've got the "Assignments" model working for teachers to add new assignments to a classroom, and I've got the "Users" model working so that teachers and students are both Users who can log in to the app. There's also a "Classroom" model, and each classroom has_many students and has_many assignments.

One of the main views needs to feature a spreadsheet form like traditional teacher gradebook programs. The spreadsheet will use students as the rows and assignments as the columns. Each cell in the spreadsheet will represent the student's score on that assignment.

From what I've learned so far, I think that my next step should be to create a join table that links students and assignments, with a third column for "score".

The part where I'm stumped is in creating the form so that the input cells are tied to the "score" column in the join table, so that entering a new number will change the student's score for that assignment.

I'm sure that articles or tutorials must exist somewhere for this concept, but I haven't been able to find any yet. At least, none that I recognize as a solution to this goal.

Thank you in advance for any guidance.

UPDATED TO INCLUDE CODE FOR MODELS

User Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
    before_save   :downcase_email
    before_create :create_activation_digest

    has_many :seminars, dependent: :destroy

    # Neccessary for finding all classes that a student is enrolled in
    has_many :aulas, dependent: :destroy,
                        foreign_key: :student_id


    validates :first_name, length: {maximum: 25},
            presence: true
    validates :last_name, length: {maximum: 25},
            presence: true
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

    has_secure_password

    validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6}, allow_nil: true

   ### Several methods that I omitted to keep the question shorter

end
```

Seminar Model:
(A "Seminar" is a class period, but I wanted to avoid the word, "Class" because I thought that would cause errors.)

```
class Seminar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to  :teacher, class_name: "User",
                        foreign_key: "user_id"
  has_many    :aulas, dependent: :destroy
  has_many    :students, through: :aulas, source: :student
  has_many    :assignments

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 40 }
end
```

Aula Model:
(Aula is Spanish for class. Again, I wanted to avoid the word, "Class". This model creates a relationship between a student user and a seminar (class period)."

```
class Aula < ApplicationRecord
    # Aula is the relationship between a student and a classperiod.

    belongs_to :student, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :seminar

    validates :student_id, presence: true
    validates :seminar_id, presence: true
end
```

Assignment model:

```
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :seminar

    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 40 }
    validates :seminar_id, presence: true
    validates :possible, presence: true
end
```

Comment: If you can edit question and show me your models ( Student, Assignment and Score ) and their relations I can help you more easily, Thanks

Comment: Haider, thank you for the suggestion. I updated the question to include all models. I don't yet have a model for "Score." My current plan is to include that in the student/assignment join table. But I'm open to changing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to show the Users x Assignments in a table and use `in place edit`, so the user can click in the cell and edit it value right there. For rails, you have a gem called "best in place" (https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) that does the trick (there's also a rails cast that shows hot to use it: http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing?view=asciicast). Hope it helps, thanks

EDIT:
Answering your question, I used best_in_place for a project manager and it performance it's really nice. Looks like you're editing on microsoft excel, or something else. 
About the backend: Well, you have a n x n relationship between student and assignments. You'll need a `assignments_student` model, for example, that belongs both to your `user` and `assignment` model and also has the `score` (take a look on nxn relationships if you're in doubt). So each row on your `assignments_student` junction table (that has two foreign keys to user and assignment table plus the `score` attribute) will be a cell on your table, in a way that you are editing the value of `score` attribute for that respective user/assignment.

Hope I made it clear. Good luck!

Comment: I did notice that gem elsewhere while I was searching for solutions. I'll watch the rails cast. Thank you!

Comment: Before viewing this Railscast, I was planning to use form fields where the teacher could input scores. The edit-in-place feature looks more user-friendly, but I wonder how it will affect performance. Won't this approach cause the app to make a hit on the server with every single edit? As opposed to traditional gradebook apps, where the teacher makes many changes, and then clicks a "Save" button.

Also, if you don't mind. I'm still stumped by my original question: How do I code the back end of the form so that each input box is tied to a student/assignment row in the join table? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes. The edited explanation was very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon), it is a gem that allows you to do:

> Dynamic nested forms using jQuery made easy

That allows you to add the "rows" to your spreadsheet-like form dynamically, based on the number of students.

Also read about Rails's `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, this is the foundation for allowing to do nested forms.

Comment: I will look into both of these. Thank you.